# A-Frame a-video not work in safari ios16.1 & iphone 12?

Tags: webgl, mobile-safari, aframe

I'm new to A-Frame. i try to make a demo which i put a-video in the scene. it work on my computer but got a black plane in my mobile device. here is the screenshot and code.

[demo run in Macos chrome & safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZM9.jpg)

[demo run in ios safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Gxt.jpg), it work on chrome.

---

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

    <script id="vertexShader" type="glsl">
      varying vec2 vUv;
      void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      }
    </script>
  
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="glsl">
      uniform sampler2D tex;
      uniform float texWidth;
      uniform float texHeight;
  
      uniform vec3 keyColor;
      uniform float similarity;
      uniform float smoothness;
      uniform float spill;
      
      varying vec2 vUv;
  
      // From https://github.com/libretro/glsl-shaders/blob/master/nnedi3/shaders/rgb-to-yuv.glsl
      vec2 RGBtoUV(vec3 rgb) {
        return vec2(
          rgb.r * -0.169 + rgb.g * -0.331 + rgb.b *  0.5    + 0.5,
          rgb.r *  0.5   + rgb.g * -0.419 + rgb.b * -0.081  + 0.5
        );
      }
  
      vec4 ProcessChromaKey(vec2 texCoord) {
        vec4 rgba = texture2D(tex, texCoord);
        float chromaDist = distance(RGBtoUV(texture2D(tex, texCoord).rgb), RGBtoUV(keyColor));
  
        float baseMask = chromaDist - similarity;
        float fullMask = pow(clamp(baseMask / smoothness, 0., 1.), 1.5);
        rgba.a = fullMask;
  
        float spillVal = pow(clamp(baseMask / spill, 0., 1.), 1.5);
        float desat = clamp(rgba.r * 0.2126 + rgba.g * 0.7152 + rgba.b * 0.0722, 0., 1.);
        rgba.rgb = mix(vec3(desat, desat, desat), rgba.rgb, spillVal);
  
        return rgba;
      }
  
      void main(void) {
        vec2 texCoord = vUv;
        gl_FragColor = ProcessChromaKey(texCoord);
      }
    </script>
  

    <script>
      AFRAME.registerShader('custom-shader', {
        init: function(data) {
          const video = document.getElementById('video')
          const texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
          this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

            uniforms: {

            tex: { value: texture },
            keyColor: {
                value: new THREE.Color(0x00ff00)
              },
              texWidth: {
                value: 1920
              },
              texHeight: {
                value: 1080
              },
              similarity: {
                value: 0.4
              },
              smoothness: {
                value: 0.08
              },
              spill: {
                value: 0.1
              }

            },

            vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
            transparent: true

          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="video" autoplay loop="true" muted="true" crossOrigin="anonymous">
          <source src="./assets/mixkit-a-woman-talking-on-the-phone-on-a-green-screen-24388-medium.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
      </a-assets>   
      <a-video material="shader: custom-shader;" webkit-playsinline playsinline position="0 0 -10" height="9" width="16" rotation="0 0 0"></a-video>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
    <script>
      const video = document.getElementById('video');
      video.play();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my [demo](https://ar.khalilhuang.com/aframe.html)

i have set some attrs to a-video like, webkit-playsinline playsinline. but it doesn't work.

is anyone know how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: afaik you must trigger the video.play() with an interaction (like a click on the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that mobile browsers require an explicit "user interaction" such as a "click" to play a video. This is required because many mobile devices use cellular data and if I embed a 1GB video on my website and autoplay it in the background it will drain your battery and you will not be happy with the data charges. Try adding a click handler to start the video and if clicking the "Start" button works then you are running into this limitation. The documentation also hints at [this](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-video-not-play)

> Mobile and desktop browsers have been tightening the video autoplay policies to preserve battery and avoid intrusive advertisements. Most browsers now require a user action (such as a click or tap event) to start video playback:

and they even provide an [example](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/video/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

    <script id="vertexShader" type="glsl">
      varying vec2 vUv;
      void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      }
    </script>
  
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="glsl">
      uniform sampler2D tex;
      uniform float texWidth;
      uniform float texHeight;
  
      uniform vec3 keyColor;
      uniform float similarity;
      uniform float smoothness;
      uniform float spill;
      
      varying vec2 vUv;
  
      // From https://github.com/libretro/glsl-shaders/blob/master/nnedi3/shaders/rgb-to-yuv.glsl
      vec2 RGBtoUV(vec3 rgb) {
        return vec2(
          rgb.r * -0.169 + rgb.g * -0.331 + rgb.b *  0.5    + 0.5,
          rgb.r *  0.5   + rgb.g * -0.419 + rgb.b * -0.081  + 0.5
        );
      }
  
      vec4 ProcessChromaKey(vec2 texCoord) {
        vec4 rgba = texture2D(tex, texCoord);
        float chromaDist = distance(RGBtoUV(texture2D(tex, texCoord).rgb), RGBtoUV(keyColor));
  
        float baseMask = chromaDist - similarity;
        float fullMask = pow(clamp(baseMask / smoothness, 0., 1.), 1.5);
        rgba.a = fullMask;
  
        float spillVal = pow(clamp(baseMask / spill, 0., 1.), 1.5);
        float desat = clamp(rgba.r * 0.2126 + rgba.g * 0.7152 + rgba.b * 0.0722, 0., 1.);
        rgba.rgb = mix(vec3(desat, desat, desat), rgba.rgb, spillVal);
  
        return rgba;
      }
  
      void main(void) {
        vec2 texCoord = vUv;
        gl_FragColor = ProcessChromaKey(texCoord);
      }
    </script>
  

    <script>
      AFRAME.registerShader('custom-shader', {
        init: function(data) {
          const video = document.getElementById('video')
          const texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
          this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

            uniforms: {

            tex: { value: texture },
            keyColor: {
                value: new THREE.Color(0x00ff00)
              },
              texWidth: {
                value: 1920
              },
              texHeight: {
                value: 1080
              },
              similarity: {
                value: 0.4
              },
              smoothness: {
                value: 0.08
              },
              spill: {
                value: 0.1
              }

            },

            vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
            transparent: true

          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="video" autoplay loop="true" muted="true" crossOrigin="anonymous">
          <source src="./assets/mixkit-a-woman-talking-on-the-phone-on-a-green-screen-24388-medium.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
      </a-assets>   
      <a-video material="shader: custom-shader;" webkit-playsinline playsinline position="0 0 -10" height="9" width="16" rotation="0 0 0"></a-video>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <script>
      const start = document.getElementById('start');
      const video = document.getElementById('video');
      start.addEventListener('click', () => {
        video.play();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i fix it with adding a click handler